# How to solve using Comparison test , I just want hint

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)^6}{n+3}$$

I know that the series is divergent , But how can show through comparison test the series is divergent? I just want hint.  Thanks

Comment: Does $(\ln(n))^6/(n+3)$ look *similar* to a summand which you have seen before and which you know diverges?

Comment: Side comment: in my opinion, the notation $\ln(n)^6$ is a bit ambiguous. It would be better as either $\ln(n^6)$ or $(\ln n)^6$.

Comment: It's $(ln(n))^6$.

Comment: @user118413 That's what I guessed. In that case, it would be better to write it as $(\ln n)^6$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $n>2\implies\log(n)>1$

Comment: Another hint: $n>3⟹n+3<2n$.